# How to access Oracle Database Trigger code from C# code

Tags: c#, oracle, triggers

How can I access a Oracle database Trigger from within C# Code?

I want to create a program that checks tables, and compares them to that table's trigger in Oracle.
I want to then see if every column in the table has a corresponding 'section' in the trigger code.
I need read/write access to the trigger via C# code.

Is this possible?
How can i access DB triggers from C# code?

Example:
TableA have 2 columns, Type and Value.
Trigger_TableA only has the following code:

```
....
IF (:OLD.TYPE IS NULL AND :NEW.TYPE IS NOT NULL) OR
   (:OLD.TYPE<> :NEW.TYPE) THEN
    vWhat_Changed := vWhat_Changed || ',TYPE='||:OLD.TYPE;
END IF;
.....
```

Trigger_TableA is incomplete, as it only is monitoring Type, and not Value.
The Trigger needs to be edited from its original state to include code to monitor the Value column
//end example

Answer (score 1):

You can find the names of the triggers that fire for a table using the [`User_Triggers`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_5448.htm) view:

```
SELECT Trigger_Name
FROM User_Triggers
WHERE Table_Name = 'my-table-name';
```

To get at the trigger code, query [`User_Source`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21644/systemtables.htm#CIACAFGJ):

```
SELECT Text
FROM User_Source
WHERE Name = 'my-trigger-name' AND Type = 'TRIGGER'
ORDER BY Line
```

---

**Addendum**

Since each column will be treated the same, something like this might be better (note it's rough and untested; tweaks are likely to be needed):

```
DECLARE
  sqlString VARCHAR2(4000);
  CURSOR colNames IS
    SELECT Column_Name
    FROM User_Tab_Columns
    WHERE Table_Name = 'this-table-name';
BEGIN
  FOR rCols IN colNames LOOP
    sqlString :=
      'BEGIN ' ||
      '  IF (:OLD.' || rCols.Column_Name || ' IS NULL AND :NEW.' || rCols.Column_Name || ' IS NOT NULL) OR ' ||
      '     (:OLD.' || rCols.Column_Name || '<> :NEW.' || rCols.Column_Name || ') THEN' ||
      '    vWhat_Changed := vWhat_Changed || ',' || rCols.Column_Name || '=' || :OLD.' || rCols.Column_Name || ';' ||
      '  END IF; ' ||
      'END;';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlString;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: can you write back to the trigger by going ''update user_source set text = 'trigger line one trigger line two' where name = 'trigger_name' and type = 'trigger'' '?

Comment: No, it's a read-only view. You'll need to pull in all the source, make your changes, and write it back using `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER`. Are you doing the same action for every column? If so, I think there's a better way than reading/parsing the trigger code. Let me know.

Comment: Each column will receive the same action.  It's basically going to be a trigger shell, then the same code chunk for each column (with the new column name).

Comment: In that case, check out the addendum to my answer. It queries the column names, creates a PL/SQL block as a string (the block does your "if changed then append to `vWhat_Changed` logic), then executes the string with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. Because `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is executing PL/SQL the string wraps the logic in a BEGIN/END. The updated answer is a road-map only; I don't have a way to test it here but it should be very close.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  That SQL code looks good, but how would i integrate this into C#? and would this EXECUTE IMMEDIATE command change the Trigger?

Comment: With the SQL code you wouldn't need to update the trigger, ever. If you add a column to the table its name will get picked up by the cursor query the next time the trigger fires. The `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is like `eval` in JavaScript - it just executes a string like it was a regular command.

Comment: Ohhhhh, you are saying to place this code inside of the trigger? in between the  CREATE OR REPLACE ... and ... END;  code?

Comment: Yes; sorry that wasn't clear. Pretty much "CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ... AS" then the code there, plus whatever else you need (`vWhat_Changed` and so forth).

Comment: each section of this code is going to execute on each iteration of this loop?  What if i have a giant 'or statement' for deletion updates?  Can i simply append code to a string and then can execute on that string once the loop is done?

Comment: Absolutely - you can call `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` as many times as you wish. If the added `DELETE` logic over-complicates the trigger code you could also create a separate `DELETE` trigger and put the logic there. Also, sorry for the late reply; your comment hit just a few minutes after I wrapped up for the day yesterday, and this was the first chance I had to respond today.